# jQuery Ajax submitting form multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am new to Ajax. I am currently submitting a form into my database using jQuery AJAX but it sends the same data multiple times in my database.

Here's my Ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id_js;

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-success', function () {
        id_js = $('#ID_TXT').val();
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'server.php',
                data: {
                    'Mark': 1,
                    'id': id_js,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#result').html(response);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Also I have tried `.one()` and `.stopImmediatePropogation()` but still no results

Comment: do you have more than one button with `.btn-success`?

Comment: No only one button in the whole page.

Comment: Don't put an event handler inside another event handler. Every time you click you add another submit handler. i

Comment: @SAMUEL Could you please `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` for the button event rather than form submit event

$(document).on('click','.btn-success', function(event){ 
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

Comment: @SAMUEL, Also could you please clarify is there a hidden button inside a form with the same classname ?  also do you see the form is getting submitted multiple time when you click on the first time or on subsequent calls?

Comment: @prasanakannan There are no hidden buttons in the form.Also, the form is submitting multiple times on subsequent calls, the first click works fine.

Comment: @SAMUEL Thanks for the clarification. Could you tell me why are you doing form submit, when you posting the data to your server with ajax? Ideally either form submission or ajax call should be done? any different in your requirement

Comment: @prasanakannan I just need the data to be posted . Do you propose that I should remove the form submit event handler ? I tried removing the form submit event handler but it still sends the data multiple times

Comment: @SAMUEL Yes you do need the form submit if you gonna to post using Ajax call. Try and let me know, if it works. I'll post my answer

Comment: @prasanakannan it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see both form submit and Ajax call are doing the same work. If you are going to post the data only with AJAX call then form submit is not required.

I hope this works well for you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function postDataToServer() {
        var id_js = $('#ID_TXT').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'server.php',
            data: {
                'Mark': 1,
                'id': id_js,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
            }
        });       
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-success', postDataToServer);
});
```

Comment: Thank Youu tonss @prasana kannan

Comment: Glad that I'm able to help you @SAMUEL

Answer (score 0):

The submit handler shouldn't be inside the click handler. Every time you click on the button, it adds another submit handler. So when you finally submit the form, it will submit it as many times as you clicked on the button.

If you want to ensure that the form isn't submitted until you've clicked on the button, add a test in the submit handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id_js;

  $(document).on('click', '.btn-success', function() {
    id_js = $('#ID_TXT').val();
  });

  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    if (id_js !== undefined) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'server.php',
        data: {
          'Mark': 1,
          'id': id_js,
        },
        success: function(response) {
          $('#result').html(response);
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("You need to click on the success button first");
    }

    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried using your method but it doesn't work the same data is going into the database multiple times